# What is the difference between Bits Per Sample, Samples Per Pixel and Bytes Per Pixel for a Bitmap Image?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, metadata

I am creating a VNC server using LibVNC library. While initializing the server I need to provide these arguments to the library.

Bits Per Sample, Samples Per Pixel and Bytes Per Pixel.

I have a Bitmap saved from MSPaint as 24bit bmp. So what will be the value of Bits per sample, samples per pixel and bytes per pixel for this image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 24-bit BMP file contains pixels that each have 3 8-bit samples (red, green, and blue).  So your image has

```
8 bits per sample
3 samples per pixel, and
3 bytes per pixel (a byte being 8 bits).
```